# How can I handle exceptions on the front end

Tags: plugin-development, templating, error

So I have some exceptions being caught in a plugin, and have to assume that in some cases a 500 error is going to occur at some point.

How can we set up Craft so that a server error displays a template rather than the default message display (assuming devMode is OFF)?

This would be something we'd want working across the whole site, not just on one plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a `500.html` template in your `craft/templates` folder, then that will get displayed on the front end when a exception bubbles all the way to the top.  The same will work for other HTTP status codes as well (`404.html`, `503.html`, etc.).

Comment: Subject to the [errorTemplatePrefix setting](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#errorTemplatePrefix)

Comment: Do 3XX responses throw an exception?